# Javascript DIV remaining in the upper right corner of any table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is sort of hard to explain, but basically I have a WYSIWYG editor and I need to make sure that a div is always in the upper right hand corner of any table when that table is clicked on. This div would have buttons that control things such as the color and borders of the specific cell that has been clicked upon.

My current code is listed in the following JSfiddle as well as the code block below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

One of my ideas was to detect the amount of columns within any table and then place the div within the last column on the first row, but I wasn't able to get it work. Though I did look for some solutions/tried my own for a good five or six hours. If anyone has any questions/suggestions please feel free to post them.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRBgC/)

```
$('.myTblBody tr td').click(function () {
    var html = $(this).text();
    var x = (this).rows[0].cells.length;
    $('#box').remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="box" style="width:50px; height:20px; background-color:#666; position:absolute; margin-top:-25px; margin-left:-50px;">');
    //If you would like to know row and col number.
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var col = $(this).index();
    //    alert('row ==' + row + "col == "+ col);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;` to style attribute of box;

Here is updated code

```
$('.myTblBody tr td').click(function(){
    var html = $(this).text();
    $('#box').remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="box" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0; width:50px; height:20px; background-color:#666">');
    //If you would like to know row and col number.
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var col = $(this).index();
    alert('row ==' + row + "col == "+ col);
});
```

Test on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/uRBgC/1/

Comment: Haha, yeah I basically just finished the exact same edits like a minute ago, thank you. Hopefully this will help others with the same issue, as well as myself of course.

Comment: :) also if you are using same div for all td create single div and you can use height attribute to show animated div.

Comment: Smart idea, and also.. There was another question, I've got it so that 'box' is deleted whenever you click on another 'td' but what about when you click out of the table? How would I make it get deleted at that point? @Ravi

Comment: `$(document).click(function() {
    $('#box').hide();
});`

Comment: Wonderful! You saved me plenty of time, my colleagues thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the div to `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0` and any parent element to `position: relative` the div will show in the top right of that element.

Comment: Aaaaah! Of course, I've been treating it like a table instead of like a div. Knew I was forgetting something important, thank you.